# is it possible to connect a public EC2 instance into company VPN for secure web service calls?

Tags: vpn, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

i'm looking for a temporary solution to allow my public web application running in EC2 to make server-side HTTP requests to a web server inside my firewall.  I looked into amazon VPC, but that seems to make new EC2 instances that are not open to the public at all.  the ec2 instances in question are running ubuntu.

what are my options for allowing my existing ec2 machine to connect to my existing inside-the-vpn web server?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you used port forwarding to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenVPN is a reliable way to achieve this. Depending on your AMI, you'll have to download it through your package management system or to compile it.

Comment: this was successful in connecting via vpn, but due to other issues we decided to go with a port forwarding solution (since this is only needed for a few days)

Answer (score 0):

OpenSwan ipsec will let you setup a site to site VPN between the a linux instance and your firewall.  There are tutorials all over the net for connecting to cisco, checkpoint, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the amazon VPC http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/ which is designed for just this purpose.  The other solution, since you said its temporary, is to [setup SSH](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/11/06/ssh-port-forwarding/) with key based authentication between your servers, and do port forwarding... For example, forward port 8080 on the AWS server over the tunnel to port 80 on the other server.  (you can forward or Reverse tunnel with SSH).  If you add your ssh connection command (and key based authentication) into upstart, it will restart ssh and rebuild the tunnel if it goes down.